# how to generate pdf in GXT/GWT?

Tags: gwt, pdf-generation

i am using GWT/EXTGWT. on click of submit button i get list of records from db. i need to export them to pdf. please suggest me how to do this?
 if data to be exported is more then that should be exported to multiple pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's little in context of GWT here, apart from the fact that you have a GWT based application. What you are really looking for is a tool that generates PDF, given data.

There are hosts of them available :

1. iText
2. jPDF Writer...

Obviously, **iText** has been the most widely known and successful one! Here's a good tutorial - http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPDF/article.html

Comment: These are nice tool to generate pdf.I used Itext in application.But issues I am facing is that HTML need to generate the pdf from itext. & If you have Form and some controls (with values) then you need to generate HTML accordingly, so the iText can generate pdf. But creating HTML manually is very difficult , and if the controls having value with not campatible with HTML then it will never generate pdf and gives error in parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Try some tools like  [itext pdf generator](http://itextpdf.com/) Searching online will give you many more options.